# Is it possible to use EXTERNAL_TEXTURE_OES to render into renderbuffer with TEXTURE_2D?

Tags: android, opengl-es, camera, textures, opengl-es-2.0

I'm going to draw Bitmap or text over video frame. Frames comes from camera and are `GlUtil.TEXTURE_OES` however my pictures are `GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D`
The way to combine them - is rendering to framebuffer. As I know, `TEXTURE_OES` is not supported by framebuffer.

How to solve this situation?

Comment: If the frames are coming from a camera, they are usually in YUV format. You can adapt a fragment shader to render them.

Comment: Therefore, I can render them as TEXTURE_2D, right? @WLGfx, Could you provide smth to read deeply about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frames are most likely to be in YUV420 format from the camera. If not you will find other formulas for converting them to RGB on the fly using a fragment shader. Here's the fragment shader I currently use for YUV420:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform sampler2D u_texturey;
uniform sampler2D u_textureu;
uniform sampler2D u_texturev;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
varying vec4 v_colorout;

void main(void)
{
    float y = texture2D(u_texturey, v_texcoord).r;
    float u = texture2D(u_textureu, v_texcoord).r - 0.5;
    float v = texture2D(u_texturev, v_texcoord).r - 0.5;
    vec4 rgb = vec4(y + 1.403 * v,
                    y - 0.344 * u - 0.714 * v,
                    y + 1.770 * u,
                    1.0);
    gl_FragColor = rgb * v_colorout;
}
```

YUV comes in 3 planes so upload them each to their texture units and the GPU does the rest.

Anthing else, just ask.

EDIT:

Use GL_LUMINANCE instead of GL_RGBA for uploading each of the textures data in their planar formats.